# Can you use sed or perl -pe to remove a part from a binary file?

Tags: regex, perl, sed, replace

I am trying to remove parts from a binary file which are between the ANSI strings "stringstart" and "stringend". Is it possible to do this with sed or perl -pe?

I am thinking about some Regex solution but I don't know how to write it or how well regex works with binary files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` is designed for handling text files rather than binary, though these days, the distinction is generally less significant than it once was.  The biggest problem is that text files do not contain zero bytes (bytes with value 0) and binary files do, and many C string processing functions stop at the first zero byte.  `sed` also reads 'lines' marked by newline characters.  Binary files can end up with long lines as a result.  Finally, there's no guarantee about the relative placement of the string start and end markers relative to newlines.  All of these characteristics make `sed` less suitable for this job than Perl is.

In Perl, I'd be sorely tempted to slurp the file into memory, use an appropriate regex to zap the data from the memory image, and then write the result back to an appropriate location.

```
perl -e 'local($/); $data = <>; $data =~ s/stringstart(.*?)stringend//gms; print $data'
```

---

Now tested - test data created using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub full_set
{
    foreach my $i (0..255) { printf "%c", $i; }
}
sub random_set
{
    my($n) = @_;
    foreach my $i (0..$n) { printf "%c", int(rand(255)); }
}

full_set;
random_set(1024);
printf("stringstart");
full_set;
random_set(512);
full_set;
printf("stringend");
random_set(256);
```

The script deletes 1045 characters from the input - which corresponds to 'stringstart', 'stringend' (20) + 2 * 256 + 513 (since `random_set(512)` prints 513 characters).

Note that the main script will read all files into memory at once.  If you want it to process one file at a time, you'll have to work a little harder; it probably ceases to be a one-liner.

Comment: @Jonathan, I think you probably want to use the lazy version `.*?` in your regex. Otherwise it will only perform one substitution, from the very first `stringstart` to the very last `stringend`. If there is only one `start/end` pair expected, the regex is of course fine -- then you can drop the `g` modifier though.

Comment: By `zero bytes` do you mean null bytes?

Comment: @vol7ron; yes - I mean bytes with value 0, aka NUL, aka U+0000, probably aka null bytes.

Comment: So is this code working with multiple start-end pairs? In my code there would be more than one start-end pairs.

Comment: @Jonathan: gotcha, reminds me of the old CGI days, parsing parameters on `\0` :)

Comment: @zsero - yes, thanks to the modification suggested by mhyfritz, the script does correctly handle multiple occurrences of the start/end markers.  I extended the test script to prove it, too (but haven't documented that extension; it isn't exactly hard, though).  Of course, the script as a whole assumes that the start marker never appears in a context where it should be preserved.  If you might ever encounter the 'stringstart' in data that must be preserved, then you need a solution that can parse the file contents accurately (meaning: probably not a pure regex solution).

Comment: /m only affects what `^` or `$` match; useless here

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach:

```
perl -pi -we'BEGIN{$/="stringend"} chomp and s/stringstart.*//s' your_binary_file
```

Comment: Perfect; why make it more difficult than it has to be? :)  Within the begin block set the input record separator.  Use the -p switch for an implicit loop with an implicit print $_.  chomp away the input record separator.  Substitute away the start token as well as whatever comes after it in the record that was terminated with the 'stringend' input record separator.  Done.  I kept contemplating the flip-flop operator, but yours is more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regular expression that kills all characters not defined after the **^** inside of **[]**. For example

```
cp /bin/ls ./binfile
file binfile
binfile: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

Do the perl pie on it:

```
perl -pi -e 's/[^[a-zA-Z0-9_+\n]//g' binfile
```

Then look at the binary file afterwards:

```
file binfile
binfile: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

You'll obviously have to add more to that command, as it'll get rid of several other would-be valid characters. But this should get you started.

Comment: I think it kills a lot of things. I want the contents of the file to be untouched, except for that part between the two ANSI strings.